# Prevent application (iscsiadm) logging to dmesg?

Tags: linux, bash, logging, iscsi, dmesg

I have an issue where running **sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p *IP* -l** logs to dmesg across all terminals on the server.

The command is run from a java application, using:

```java
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash", "-c", "sudo iscsiadm -m discovery -t st -p *IP* -l");
```

I have tried the following:

1. Apppending `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end of the `iscsiadm discovery...` command
2. Capturing input streams from the returned progress (`process.getInputStream()` and `process.getErrorStream()`)
3. Appending `> /dev/null 2>&1` to the software launching the Jar.

None of the above attempts prevent logging across all virtual terminals. The log starts `[some_num.some_dec] LOG_MESSAGE` which suggests it is outputting to `dmesg`? If this is true how do I prevent this? Currently it makes the system impossible to debug because it's printing over the terminal prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

iscsiadm controls the kernel iSCSI subsystem, and the messages do not actually come from the program – they come directly from the kernel driver.

Use `dmesg -n warning` or boot with the `loglevel=4` to reduce the amount of useless messages.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed.

It turns out it was not iscsiadm logging to dmesg, it was the mount command afterwards because the blockdev did not exist.

I have modified my java code to try `iscsiadm -m discovery...` then run `iscsiadm -m session` to determine if the appropriate device has a connection or not prior to mounting.